# .keyup event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('input[name="list_checkbox_ids[]"], #frame, input[name="del_list_ids[]"]').on('keyup', function() {
   $('#button_link').prop('disabled', ! $('input[name="list_checkbox_ids[]"]:checked').length);
});
```

The scenario is, I click on search button that generates a list of checkboxes. `button_link` should be defaulted to `disabled` until I select one of the checkboxes. Now in the above code, Howcome it does not remove the `disabled`? I tried looking for errors in the console but cannot find one. Pls help.

`list_checkbox_ids` are dynamically loaded on the page.

Comment: Did you check if `$('input[name="list_checkbox_ids[]"], #frame, input[name="del_list_ids[]"]')` selects inputs with the type text (or similar)

Comment: Can you provide html code? With it will be easier to help you

Comment: #frame is an input field

Comment: Note: You should be updating the disabled state from *both* the keypress and the checkbox `change` event.

Comment: A "correct" solution will depend on your HTML layout too. How many sets of these controls are there etc. Can you provide HTML too?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change

**This**

```
$('input[name="list_checkbox_ids[]"], #frame, input[name="del_list_ids[]"]').on('keyup', function() {
   $('#button_link').prop('disabled', !$('input[name="list_checkbox_ids[]"]:checked').length);
 });
```

**Into this(using event delegation) for dynamically created content**

```
 $(document).on('keyup','input[name="list_checkbox_ids[]"], #frame, input[name="del_list_ids[]"]', function() {
   $('#button_link').prop('disabled', !$('input[name="list_checkbox_ids[]"]:checked').length);
 });
```

Comment: The same thing happened. button_link will not appear when I click on the checkboxes.

Comment: did you type something on input field with id name `frame` after checked the checkbox? Your button will show up after the checkbox was ticked AND type something on input with id `frame`. If you just want the button to be enabled by just ticking the checkbox, then the `keyup` function in not suited well, should used `click` event instead. try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/pamor1ay/1/

Comment: try this link and see what happened there http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/pamor1ay/2/